# LINQ grouping without changing the order

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects that sort of look like this:

```
+-------+------+
| Group | Item |
+-------+------+
| A     | A-1  |
| A     | A-2  |
| B     | B-3  |
| B     | B-4  |
| A     | A-5  |
| A     | A-6  |
| B     | B-7  |
+-------+------+
```

Is there any way to group these items with LINQ while keeping the order. The above table would result in 4 groups. `AA, BB, AA, B`. With the GroupBy function I would end up with only two groups, `AAAA, BBB`.

Some example code:

```
@foreach (var group in Model.AllItems.GroupBy(g => g.Group))
{
    <h1>Group</h1>
   foreach (var groupItem in group)
   {
        <h2>@groupItem.Item</h2>
   }
}
```

The output of this code with the above table would be

## Group

- A-1
- A-2
- A-5
- A-6

## Group

- B-3
- B-4
- B-7

> Note, I have changed the table to better illustrate my problem

What I want the output to be is

## Group

- A-1
- A-2

## Group

- B-3
- B-4

## Group

- A-5
- A-6

## Group

- B-7

Comment: Please post your GroupBy statement, I'm not sure I understand by which criteria you are grouping

Comment: You are grouping by which condition ?

Comment: I have updated the question with an example.

Comment: The answer in the duplicate question works. I just didn't have the vocabulary to remember "contiguous" :)